# Win32 still best for Windows game development?

Tags: c++

I'm looking to start a new project to work on in my free time that covers a lot of areas of Computer Science and I've decided on a game (most likely flight simulator or simple 2D side-scroller).  Anyway, I do a lot of C#/Java development at work writing business applications so I'm looking to do a game in C++ (I have used C#/XNA for games previously).

However, I'm trying to find a good framework for C++ game development.  I have used Qt before but don't believe this is suitable for what I am trying to achieve.  Is Win32 and OpenGL still the best for C++ game development?

Also, I want to keep this pretty OO, any recommendations for wrapping the Win32 for game development?  Or does OpenGL provide abstractions to help?

Comment: try sfml http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: "*most likely flight simulator or simple 2D side-scroller*" Oh yeah, those two are definitely on the same technical tier. >_>

Comment: Was that a requirement? No...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've experienced, the Win API is a complete mess. I'd recommend using something like SDL and save yourself the trouble. As a bonus, this will also make it cross platform. You can also use OpenGL with SDL.

SDL is still a bit low level and has a C style API, so you'll need to write your own OO wrappers. I've heard that SFML and Allegro are popular alternatives but I have less experience with them.

Comment: SDL is even worse than the Windows API. Can you say "global variable"?

Comment: +1 for SDL. I recently ported my own game-related code which has always used SDL, to OS X, with few headaches. SDL just works and you can find many guides and tutorials for it. IMO it's not smart to limit yourself to Windows by going with WinAPI.

Comment: I thought SDL was relatively outdated?

Comment: @DeadMG Have you ever used the Win32 API? SDL may not be perfect, but it WAY better then win32 API. Also, as he said, it is portable, which is a bonus.

Comment: At least it doesn't define min and max as macros (You can define NOMINMAX to stop this but it's still a big landmine for beginners).

Comment: @keelerjr12 They are working on SDL 2.0 (it was going to be 1.3, then they decided to rename to 2.0).

Comment: @fbafelipe: I have used the Windows API, actually, and SDL is definitely worse.

Comment: But aren't DirectX and its associated interfaces easier to manage than OpenGL?  If so, then isn't this a valid reason to prefer the Win API?

Comment: @thb Some people just don't care about portability. For that reason (portability) I tend to avoid every API that Microsoft makes. Awesome stuff like MinGW keeps me happy because my primary OS is actually Windows.

Comment: I'm not really going for portability either.  Just looking for a fun project to work on in my spare time.

Comment: My opinion has always been that portable code is more fun to write. There's more stuff to test it on. And once it's finished it's that much more useful and robust. It's like crafting a sculpture out of steel rather than paper-mache.

Comment: @StevenLu:  That's ironic.  Perhaps this is, too:  my primary OS is actually Debian.  The reason for my comment was just to ask the question:  one likes to keep at least a slightly open mind.  (My own work makes me more likely to use LAPACK than SDL, so I don't claim to know much about the matter in any case.)

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing the irony. LAPACK and SDL tackle entirely different tasks. I use both. :) And I wasn't attacking your point. I'd love to learn DirectX one day. But the amount of problems I have with Sharepoint and the like at work keeps me away on general principle. Anyway, I think I just came up with a cool way to think about code portability. It's about reducing its entropy and it gives it an inherent quality of elegance.

Answer (score 2):

SFML is probably the closest you can get. Most people using 2D rendering roll their own, and most using 3D go with either something like Irrlicht, or roll their own.

As for OGL, the OGL API is horrific- it's even worse than the Windows API. At least that is OO, C-style, instead of just plain old global-variables-up-wazoo.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/index.html). It looks to be minimalistic (in a good way).